# Android - How can I create a selector for Layouts (like an ImageButton selector)

Tags: android, xml, background, selector, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton and a LinearLayout wrapping that button, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeButtonLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/p_buttons_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/homeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10px"
            android:background="@drawable/home_icon"
            android:onClick="goBackToCameraScreen" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I put a background around the ImageButton **in the LinearLayout**, as you can see above.

I want to be able to change that background (that is, **the background of the LinearLayout**, not the background of the ImageButton) when the user clicks on the ImageButton. I could do that programmatically, but I want to do that via XML. I could easily change the background **of the ImageButton** by writing a selector, like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

That's ***EXACTLY*** what I want, except that I want to **change the LinearLayout background, and not the ImageButton background**. How can I create a XML selector just like the one above, but that actually changes the background of the LinearLayout instead of the ImageButton background??

Thank you in advance!! =)

Comment: if somebody wants to get full solution, check this repository: https://github.com/shamanland/AndroidLayoutSelector there is custom clickable/checkable ```LinearLayout``` like a ```ToggleButton```

Answer (score 4):

Set the selector to your `LinearLayout` and add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to it.

In selector, replace all button backgrounds with layout backgrounds.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/homeButtonLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10px"
        android:background="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:onClick="goBackToCameraScreen" />
</LinearLayout>
```

selector `layout_bg_selector.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="#00F000" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="#0000F0" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Hi userSeven7s. Thanks for replying. Could you be more specific? I have tried to set the selector in my LinearLayout's background property, but it didn't work. I guess that's because LinearLayouts don't have those "item states" like "state_pressed", "state_focused"...

Comment: I must be missing something because it didn't work. Even when I click outside my button (but inside the layout), it doesn't change the color of the LinearLayout).

Comment: see if removing `descendantFocusability` changes anything.. if it works add focusable="false" to button..

Comment: Nothing worked. I have tried all the combinations of focus (with and without descendantFocusability) and nothing! =(

Comment: I have updated my code with my latest try. I have tried other combinations of focusable as well without success.

Comment: is `p_buttons_background` the selector xml name?

Comment: Yes, that's the selector! Did it work there? I have tried again here and it still didn't work!! =(

Comment: We are almost there! Now it works if I click outside the button, but inside the LinearLayout. But I also want to be able to change the background when the user clicks on the button, because I have an onClick set for the button that does a bunch of things...

Comment: Any new ideas userSeven7s?? I am starting to think that there is no way to do what I want... =(

Answer (score 1):

I think the questioner is dead by now :XD

but this is the solution

add this two lines of code to your layout:

```
android:clickable = "true"
```

and

```
android:focusable = "true"
```

the main sample is

> we have this constraint layout like :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutSample"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> and the ( layout_selector.xml ) like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_focused" android:state_focused="true" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_default" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and for ( bg_pressed.xml ) and ( bg_focused.xml ) and ( bg_default.xml ) as we used in selector before we need to declare them in drawable folder like :

> bg_pressed.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#00ff00" />
</shape>
```

> bg_focused.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#ff0000" />
</shape>
```

> bg_default.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

> now put your image view or something else inside the layout and try
>   some clicks :) (read the question!)

hope this will help you ...