# Show a selection mask effect on click on LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Please see the layout below. I want to show a selection highlight on the entire `LinearLayout` if  the user touches the `ImageView` or preferably entire layout. This is like a onclick effect. Although I have a selector its not working. How can I make this work?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnFromEasy"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/normal_button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/normal_button_size"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/animals" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/easy"
        android:textColor="@color/subtitle_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="Blue" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="White" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876119/android-how-can-i-create-a-selector-for-layouts-like-an-imagebutton-selector

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple code.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_image_pressed" />  // image    
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/background_image_default" /> // image
</selector>
```

and inside LinearLayout add `android:clickable="true"`

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
    ...>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Add android:clickable="true" to properties of LinearLayout and it work

Your code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

-> add

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_selector"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:clickable="true">
```

Line `android:layout_width="0dp"` makes the layout can't be visible so I change it to `"wrap_content"`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tired this, highlight happens only when i click on spaces controls are not overlapping with linear layout. I also tried android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants", but that didnt make a change. Note that linear layout is a child of two other linear layouts as well.